# How to program effectively composite coordination in Vert.x

Tags: java, vert.x

I'm wondering what is the best way to run the following set of calls asynchronously in Vert.x.

```
C1: [v1, v2] +--> C2(v1): x --> C2.1(x): xx --|
             |--> C3(v2): y --> C3.1(y): yy --+- C4(xx, yy)
```

As for notation `C1: [v1, v2]` means call `C1` which returns an array of values `[v1, v2]`.

What I'm thinking about, at the moment, is:

```
Future c1 = Future.future();
call_C1(some_input, handler -> {
    // ... do something
    c1.complete([v1, v2]);
});

c1.compose(array -> {
    // process data and then call C2-->C2.1 and C3-->C3.1
    Future c2 = Future.future();
    call_C2(array[0], c2.completer());

    Future c21 = Future.future();
    c2.compose(x -> {
        // process x and then call C2.1
        call_C2_1(x, h -> {
            // process result and complete c21
            c21.complete(xx);
        });
    });

    Future c3 = Future.future();
    call_C3(array[1], c3.completer());

    Future c31 = Future.future();
    c3.compose(y -> {
        // process y and then call C3.1
        call_C3_1(y, h -> {
            c31.complete(yy);
        });
    });

    CompositeFuture.all(c21, c31).setHandler(h -> {
        xx = h.result().resultAt(0);
        yy = h.result().resultAt(1);
        // process xx and yy
    });
});
```

I hope it is correct but is there a better, more natural or more effective way to combine all these calls? Any help appreciated.

Comment: It does look correct, except it's missing the C4 call :) There is no "better" way, but you might consider looking at RxJava and the Vert.x rxified API, which may feel more natural to you.

Comment: Good point! Now, I'm scratching my head how to compose C4 call with the top-level `c1` rather then nest it deep in the composite future handler. Anyway, would you be able to show "equivalent" composite call in RxJava+Vert.x? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Consider looking at RxJava and the [Vert.x rxified API](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-rx/java/), which may feel more natural to you.

Here's an example:

```
  interface C1Result {
    Object v1();

    Object v2();
  }

  static Single<C1Result> C1() {
    return null;
  }

  static Single<Object> C2(Object v1) {
    return null;
  }

  static Single<Object> C21(Object x) {
    return null;
  }

  static Single<Object> C3(Object v2) {
    return null;
  }

  static Single<Object> C31(Object y) {
    return null;
  }

  static Single<Void> C4(Object xx, Object yy) {
    return null;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    C1().flatMap(c1Result -> {

      Single<Object> xxSingle = C2(c1Result.v1()).flatMap(x -> {
        return C21(x);
      });

      Single<Object> yySingle = C3(c1Result.v2()).flatMap(y -> {
        return C31(y);
      });

      return Single.merge(Single.zip(xxSingle, yySingle, (xx, yy) -> {
        return C4(xx, yy);
      }));

    }).subscribe(v -> {
      // Success
    }, throwable -> {
      // Failure
    });

  }
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. I'm not that familiar with Observer but I can see it's rather minor syntactical change. Also, the C4 call is done from inside of the C1 handler. It'd be cleaner for me if C4 can be combined at the level of C1... Think, for example, of more calls following C4. Cheers, Jacek